# How to add request id in Django logs without modifying logger call?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, logging

I want to add request and user ids with logs of my Django project. Ways I found on internet need me to send extra request with every logger call like this,

`logger.info('This is my info log line', extras={ 'request', request }`)

But I **don't** want to modify every existing logger call. Is it possible to this with handlers/formatters?

Answer (score 2):

If request is a constant in one logger, you can use custom Filter to archive this goal:

```
import logging
class CustomFilter(logging.Filter):
    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request
    def filter(self, record):
        record.request = self.request
        return True
```

Then add `%(request)s` into your formatter, and add CustomFilter to your logger's filters:

```
logger.addFilter(CustomFilter(CONSTANT_REQUEST))
handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(request)s %(levelname)s %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

Comment: What did you mean by "If request is a constant in one logger"?

Comment: Also, how request will be passed to __init__?

Comment: Can I pass request in django logging settings ?
Like if I want to do:
```
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '(request)': 'app.custom_logger.UpgradFilter',
        }
    },

```